# Heuristics for minimum path cover of undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory, heuristics, hamiltonian-paths

Suppose you would like to find a set of paths on an undirected connected graph that ensures every vertex is visited exactly once while minimising the number of paths used. In this case, a "path" may consist of just a single vertex. I understand that this might be similar to the Hamiltonian path problem which is NP-complete, but I'm wondering how this could be extended if multiple paths are allowed.

How should one go about this? Would this also be NP-complete? If so, are there any interesting ways to "minimise" it but not necessarily to the smallest extent?

**Update:**
It seems that this is called the minimum path cover problem, which is NP-hard for undirected connected graphs.

Here is a naive heuristic I have come up with so far:

**1. Turn the graph into a DAG that preserves as many edges as possible.**

Pick an arbitrary ordering of the vertices. For every pair of vertices $v, w$, only keep the edge $v \rightarrow w$ where $w > v$. This guarantees that any path would go from left to right along the ordering, ensuring that the graph is acrylic.

*What are some more optimal ways we can pick a DAG subgraph such that the next step can find a more optimal solution?*

**2. Find the minimum path cover on the DAG.**

Split every vertex $v$ into vertices $v_i$ and $v_o$, which only preserve the incoming and outgoing edges of $v$ respectively. At this point, we have a bipartite graph with only incoming-edge vertices on one side and outgoing-edge vertices on the other.

In a minimum path cover, there is at most one incoming and outgoing edge for every vertex. Thus, we can construct a minimum path cover by simply finding the maximum cardinality matching—a set of as many edges as possible such that all vertices are of maximum degree one—of the bipartite graph. This can be done using the Hopcraft-Karp algorithm.

Comment: Of course it’s NP-complete, because the decision problem of whether one path suffices is exactly the Hamiltonian path decision problem. But perhaps there is an interesting approximation algorithm or heuristic approach to your problem.

Comment: *minimum path cover problem*